# Timing specifications: can a spec be converted from units of +/- ms to parts per million?

Tags: clock-speed

I have a test specification that requires time base uncertainty of +/- X ppm or less.  I understand that ppm is a common way to specify crystal accuracy.  But in the performance specification for my measurement equipment they are specifying time base accuracies in terms of +/- Y ms.

*Is there a method to convert from one to the other*?

For example, is there a way to convert the following accuracy specification in terms of ppm?

```
Pulse Width:
Range: 1 ms to 50 ms
Accuracy: ± 0.1 ms
```

Note, I cannot find an actual reference clock rate in the entire equipment performance specification.

Comment: Other than with the period?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - Not sure what you mean.

Comment: PPM is relative. If you don't have a base then you can't calculate it.

Comment: Yup you need to know what clock rate the equipment is using then you can do the math.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - I have added the actual specification I am questioning in my post.

Comment: @Trevor - So far I have not been able to find an actual reference to clock rate in this instrument specification.

Comment: You COULD fudge a number out of that and assume that the 0.1 is at mid range, \$=1000000 * 0.1 / 25 = ±4000ppm\$ but that is not really the same thing.

Comment: Well with that specification you get a range of ppm, which is probably why they didn't use it. 0.1 ms is 2000 ppm for 50 ms and 100000 ppm for 1 ms. If you'd use 2000 ppm as a measure you'd create a system with +/- 2 µs accuracy to get 2000 ppm at 1 ms.

Comment: @Arsenal - I would accept that as an answer if you care to post.  In my scribbles here this morning, I started to come to the same conclusion, but until today, had zero experience with that the terminology, and was not certain of how to use it.

Comment: There may be a good reason why it isn't quoted in percentage terms, so imposing an arbitrary measure could be misleading.

Comment: @Chu - agreed.  I would want to make decisions based on worst case of the published operating range, but having confirmation about even how to convert from a time representation (+/- 0.1 ms) to ppm has been my challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specification gives an absolute accuracy for a range of pulses.

This means in turn, if you convert it to a relative accuracy like ppm (or %) you get a range of accuracy. This is quite unusual and would probably lead to difficulties interpreting the specification.

With your example you'd end up with:

\$0.1~\text{ms} / 1~\text{ms} = 0.1\$ or 100000 ppm

\$0.1~\text{ms} / 50~\text{ms} = 0.002\$ or 2000 ppm

So with these values, how would you accurately describe the specification you have now?

Accuracy: 100000 ppm going down to 2000 ppm in a reciprocal way according to the set period. (don't know if that's even a correct expression there)

Or maybe "2000 ppm at 50 ms" but that leaves room for interpretation as well.

It gets a mess. So you might be tempted to just choose the stringent measure, which would be 2000 ppm.

Someone implementing this would end up creating a system which is capable of creating pulses with +/- 2 µs because the worst case scenario is 1 ms and 2000 ppm.

Now that is a lot more difficult than a system with +/- 0.1 ms.

So for this scenario a relative accuracy doesn't hold well. If you have to do a worst case analysis, with this specification you'd get 100000 ppm.